# How to combine multiple lookAt

Tags: three.js

How can I combine two lookAt without creating a roll.
The individual lookAt are fine with the up vector (no roll) but if I try to multiply two lookAt matrix, it does not work anymore.
Thanks

Comment: What are your trying to do? Can you show your code?

Comment: I'm trying to rotate a pyramid around is tip (ptA) to an arbitrary point (ptB) but instead of having the centre of the pyramid align with ptB, I need one of the corners at the base of the pyramid (ptC) to align with ptB. So I do lookAt-A (ptA to ptB) and lookAt-B (ptA to ptC) and I mutliply lookAt-A by the inverse of lookAt-B. It works, it align ptC (corner of the pyramid) with ptB but the multiplication seems induce a rotation along the pyramid normal Z. So in both lookAt, the pyramid X stay coplanar with the world XY plane but I don't know how to combine them and keep the X coplanar...

Comment: Perhaps you can edit this fiddle so your question becomes clear: http://jsfiddle.net/tFm9U/.

Comment: Hi West, here is the fiddle edit http://jsfiddle.net/tFm9U/1/

Comment: You need to do something different. Set `pyramidDestination.rotation.order = "YXZ";`. Experiment with euler rotations so you understand what that means. Then `pyramidDestination.rotation.set( theta, phi, 0 )`. The pyramid will not "roll". http://jsfiddle.net/tFm9U/3/

Comment: We tried with a couple of techniques but can't seems to find the right math to do this, the corner of the pyramid will never align without "roll". Here is the fiddle of what we tried (Quaternion, Matrices, Euler) http://jsfiddle.net/tFm9U/4/

Comment: Getting closer with Euler and cross product http://jsfiddle.net/tFm9U/6/ still not working...

Comment: My approach is similar, and it works if the target is the center of the base of the pyramid, instead of the corner of the base: http://jsfiddle.net/tFm9U/8/. I know that it is not what you are looking for, but it may give you some inspiration: http://jsfiddle.net/tFm9U/8/